Arbitrary sorting of non-comparable elements? (Lean 4)
In Lean I'm working a lot with partial orders, and they have this property that not every element is necessarily comparable (i.e. for a, b in P where P is a partial order, it may not be true that either a < b or b < a).
Suppose I have a set defined as follows:
import Mathlib.Data.Fintype.Basic

variable {P : Type*} [PartialOrder P] [Fintype P]

def pairs (m : P → ℤ) : Set (List ℤ × List P) := {(p.map m, p) | p : List P }

def sorted_pairs (m : P → ℤ) : List (List ℤ × List P) := sorry 

I can order the list to an extent by using the lexicographic order on p.map m, but after that there is the issue that two different lists in P might map to the same list in ℤ, say p1 and p2, in which case the lexicographic order doesn't allow me to differentiate between (p1.map m, p1) and (p2.map m, p2), since ```p1.map m = p2.map m```. In such a case, is there a way to arbitrarily order the elements of this set?

Ok, so like your last question, this set you give is not finite so it can’t be sorted into a finite list.  But I assume like your last question, you are interested in a particular finite subset of the lists.  But to turn a finite set into a list, use Finset.toList.

Finset.toList uses the axiom of choice.  If you want the list to respect the partial order as much as possible or to respect another order like the one induced by the map m, then there should be code which completes a partial order to a linear order (again, using the axiom of choice).

Hi Jason, thanks for the help! I thought I understood previously why my set was infinite, but it seems not. Could you please explain again why the set I define here is not finite? In my head if P is finite then there are finitely many List P type elements and so the set seems finite.

Assume P is Bool (a finite type).  Then List P includes [], [true], [true, true], [true, true, true], …
